# Testing object assignment in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, azure-functions

I am writing an Azure Function and persisting data to a CosmosDB.
It works like this:

```js
const preloadShipmentTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {
    if (req.body) {
        const body: Body = req.body

        context.bindings.cosmosDocument = JSON.stringify(body);
        context.res = {
            status: 200,
            body: 'Successfully persisted document'
        };
    }
}
```

And here's a test for the same functionality:

```js
test('returns 200', async () => {
    let contextMock: Context = mock<Context>()

    const body = createBody()
    const request = {
        body: body
    }

    let context = instance(contextMock)
    context.bindings = {
        cosmosDocument: undefined
    }

    await httpFunction(context, request)

    verify(contextMock.log(`log`)).once()

    expect(context.bindings.cosmosDocument).toBeDefined()
    expect(context.bindings.cosmosDocument).toEqual(JSON.stringify(body))

    expect(context.res).toBeDefined()
    expect(context.res!.status).toBe(200)
    expect(context.res!.body).toBe('Successfully persisted document')
})
```

Bindings in the `Context` object looks like this in the definition:

```js
/**
 * Input and trigger binding data, as defined in function.json. Properties on this object are dynamically
 * generated and named based off of the "name" property in function.json.
 */
bindings: {
    [key: string]: any;
};
```

I am using ts-mockito for this.

Now I'd like to test what happens when the object assignment fails, e.g. writing to database fails:

```js
when(context.bindings.cosmosDocument).thenThrow(new Error(''))
```

Obviously this won't work since cosmosDocument is not a mock:

> TypeError: this.methodToStub is not a function

How can do I do this in TypeScript? Is it a simple matter to rearrange my code, or do I have to dive into mechanics of the Azure Function framework?

Comment: It's *not* a function, you set it to undefined. What happens if you make it a function?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried making it a mock to verify:  `cosmosDocument: mock()` and then `verify(context.bindings.cosmosDocument()).once()`. However this just fails with `TypeError: context.bindings.cosmosDocument is not a function`. I never call this as a function, a value is just assigned to it. Will this really help? Won't my function be overwritten when I run anyway? When I run this the `cosmosDocument` is just a json string.

Comment: Oh, I see. Presumably that's implemented via https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

Comment: Thanks for the clue, seems reasonable. I will look into if I can spy a setter somehow.

Comment: You don't need to spy, *you're creating the context*, just create one that throws an error when that property is assigned to.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks a ton, that did the trick. I updated my question with the snippet that solved it. If you write an answer I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: @jokarl Hi, jokarl. if jonrsharpe's solution helps you, please mark his answer. It is very important.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to throw an error on the assignment:

```
context.bindings.cosmosDocument = JSON.stringify(body);
```

you have two options:

1. Leave `context.bindings` as `undefined`, which will lead to `TypeError: Cannot set property 'cosmosDocument' of undefined`; or
2. Implement a [`set` accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) that throws an error of your choosing:

   ```
   context.bindings = {
     set cosmosDocument(document: string) {
       throw new Error("");
     },
   };
   ```